# ReadProcessMemory reads an empty string

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32, win32gui, activepython

I'm trying to read the text of desktop icons using win32gui (I must use win32 because I also need to get the positions of the icons and they should match the text).

I used the code in here: [Use Python to extract ListView items from another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872480/use-python-to-extract-listview-items-from-another-application) and it returned a list with empty strings. I tried to check return codes and other values and they all make sense.

> If the control is in the same process as your code, it should work. If it's in a different process (as "another application" suggests), then this doesn't work (or at least it shouldn't). Check the error codes, you should get something along the lines of "permission denied".

But the desktop is in a different process and I got no error codes!

To get the handle of the desktop window I used the `get_desktop()` function that I posted in the solution section in here: [How to get desktop item count in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663875/how-to-get-desktop-item-count-in-python/)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: hmm... reminds me of a game trainer.

Comment: game trainers use readprocessmemory and writeprocessmemory to hack games by rewriting memory. Soo off-topic but whatevs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! It was the `LVITEM` struct that was wrong.

The struct I used was for 32 bit architecture but my computer is 64 bit (the python is 32 bit but it doesn't matter).

This [forum](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=1464.30) has the assembly answer. And here is a follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750589/lvitem-for-windows-64-bit) which contains the struct in python.

Basically, the `stateMask` field has to be 64 bits long and all the pointers should also be 64 bits long (`pszText`, `puColumns` and `piColFmt`) and also `lParam`. I don't understand the why `stateMask` should be 64 bit yet, but that's what the follow up question is for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of someone with the same problem, where the listview was in another process so it couldn't be read directly:

http://www.xiandg.com/2094118/codep1/get-text-of-lvitem-with-lvmgetitem-and-sendmessage-in-c

The answer:

> Because the memory block that contains the text is owned by the other
>   process, you will need to pull a few tricks to marshal the text from
>   the process into your process.

That procedure is detailed here: http://taylorza.blogspot.com/2009/08/archive-hacking-my-way-across-process.html

Comment: Thank you but I'm still struggling, what's missing from the code in the link I posted? (Use Python to extract ListView items from another application)

Comment: I was successful to write that block manually and read it (the block is in another process). So the problem is in the SendMessage.